# How to configure the entrypoint/cmd for docker-based python3 lambda functions?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I switched from a zip-based deployment to a docker-based deployment of two lambda functions (which are used in an API Gateway). Both functions where in the same zip file and I want to have both functions in the same docker-based container (meaning I can't use the `cmd` setting in my Dockerfile (or to be precise need to overwrite it anyway). Previously, I used the handler attribute in the cloudformation template for specifying which handler function to call in which module, e.g.

```
...
  ConfigLambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: config.handler
      ...
...
  LogLambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: logs.handler
      ...
```

but with a docker-based build one has to define an `ImageConfig`, i.e.

```
...
  LogLambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      ImageUri: !Ref EcrImageUri
      FunctionName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-Logs"
      ImageConfig:
        WorkingDirectory: /var/task
        Command: ['logs.py']
        EntryPoint: ['/var/lang/bin/python3']
...
  ConfigLambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      ImageUri: !Ref EcrImageUri
      FunctionName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-Config"
      ImageConfig:
        WorkingDirectory: /var/task
        Command: ['config.py']
        EntryPoint: ['/var/lang/bin/python3']
```

I'm a bit stuck because this does not work, no matter what combination I pass to the command array. If I fire a test event in the AWS console, I get the following error

```
RequestId: <uuid> Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason
Runtime.ExitError
```

Judging from the full output, the file is loaded and executed, but the handler function is not invoked (there is some output from a logging setup function which is called right after the module imports). The section in the AWS documentation on python3 based lambdas state that naming for handlers should be file_name.function (e.g. function_lambda.lambda_handler), but this doesn't give any clues on how do to this for command array in a ImageConfig.

How do I set the Command section correctly for my lambda function in my cloudformation template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the container you deploy to AWS Lambda has to implement the [Lambda Runtime Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-images.html#runtimes-api-client). AWS Lambda isn't a generic docker container runtime, it only supports running containers that implement a specific interface. The easiest way to ensure your container implements this interface is to base it on one of the AWS provided [base images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-images.html).

Note how the `ENTRYPOINT` for [the base Python images](https://ENTRYPOINT%20%5B%22/lambda-entrypoint.sh%22%5D) isn't `python` it is a custom script. That script expects the `COMMAND` to be in the same `app.handler` format it is in for non-container based Lambda functions.

See an example Dockerfile [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html).